How do I update a destination after upgrading the custom destination connector in Airbyte
So here is my scenario.

I have a custom destination connector and I have added it to airbyte via the UI
I have used the custom destination connector to create a connection and everything works fine
Now I have made changes to the custom destination connector and I have updated it via the UI on airbyte.

My question now is, how do I update the connection created in step 2 to now use the updated custom destination connector?

You should go to the list of Airbyte's destination connectors and change the version of the connector to that one that you want to use now. Note that youshould use different version numbers every time you update your connectors for Airbyte to recognize the new one. This is something you should take into account when building your connectors with Docker: just define a new vesion number in your alias and refer it as so in the connectors list.

But doing this does not make already created connection to use the newupdated  connector right?

Note that you should use different version numbers every time you update your connectors for Airbyte to recognize the new one. This is something you should take into account when building your connectors with Docker: define a new version number in your alias and refer to it as so in the connectors list.
The scheduler checks the version of the connector every time it starts. So, it will update to the version you have set in the list of connectors. Note that you can Change the connector to the new version and it will synchronize by verifying the one you are setting. Indeed, you can use the latest but you have to define it as well in your repository. Also, I would suggest you to redefine the latest alias to point to your production version of the connector.
The image below is more illustrative.


Sorry but it is still not clear. So in a scenario where I create a destination, then a source and then a connection. Now I need to update the destination to a new version, after I update it in the UI you shared, will the old connection now use this new version? or do I need to delete the connection and recreate it so that it picks up the updated destionation?

Yes, every time Airbyte launches the connector it will use the version you have declared in the UI. Note that it will fail if the version you are setting is not tagged as so in your connector repository. When creating a connector you will find a field to specify the Docker image tag. This is the field that you can update through this UI. Indeed, you should create the new version and push it to the repo with the same alias (tag).
